# Why could UpdateTip be taking so long?

Tags: bitcoind

It has been 10 days since I ran bitcoind. When I opened it yesterday, I waited for about 40 minutes during which I could do not much except for waiting because my computer became so slow (high CPU usage), while bitcoin was running 'UpdateTip'. In my log file you can see about 40 minutes of this activity. Ultimately, I had to shut down my computer because I had other stuff to do. What could cause this process to be so CPU and time intensive?

Note that this is not an exceptional situation: it happens every time I open bitcoind (the longer the time between the last open, the longer it takes to run this UpdateTip thing).

Please note that I download the new database files by ryncing them from another computer - in case that may affect the situation.

Here is my log file:

```
2014-07-24 15:36:02 Bitcoin version v0.9.2.1-g354c0f3-beta (Thu, 19 Jun 2014 09:51:15 +0200)
2014-07-24 15:36:02 Using OpenSSL version OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
2014-07-24 15:36:02 Using BerkeleyDB version Berkeley DB 5.3.28: (September  9, 2013)
2014-07-24 15:36:02 Default data directory /home/jny/.bitcoin
2014-07-24 15:36:02 Using data directory /home/jny/.bitcoin
2014-07-24 15:36:02 Using at most 125 connections (1024 file descriptors available)
2014-07-24 15:36:02 Using 2 threads for script verification
2014-07-24 15:36:02 Using wallet wallet.dat
2014-07-24 15:36:02 init message: Verifying wallet...
2014-07-24 15:36:02 CDBEnv::Open : LogDir=/home/jny/.bitcoin/database ErrorFile=/home/jny/.bitcoin/db.log
2014-07-24 15:36:02 init message: Loading block index...
2014-07-24 15:36:02 Opening LevelDB in /home/jny/.bitcoin/blocks/index
2014-07-24 15:36:03 Opened LevelDB successfully
2014-07-24 15:36:03 Opening LevelDB in /home/jny/.bitcoin/chainstate
2014-07-24 15:36:03 Opened LevelDB successfully
2014-07-24 15:36:10 LoadBlockIndexDB(): last block file = 159
2014-07-24 15:36:10 LoadBlockIndexDB(): last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=460, size=119319801, heights=311820...312279, time=2014-07-21...2014-07-24)
2014-07-24 15:36:10 LoadBlockIndexDB(): transaction index disabled
2014-07-24 15:36:10 LoadBlockIndexDB(): hashBestChain=000000000000000004cc093a27bb1b1380d669d57b7a6c702ce0984f12653062 height=308577 date=2014-06-30 07:52:18 progress=0.921759
2014-07-24 15:36:10 init message: Verifying blocks...
2014-07-24 15:36:10 Verifying last 288 blocks at level 0
2014-07-24 15:36:13 No coin database inconsistencies in last 0 blocks (0 transactions)
2014-07-24 15:36:13  block index           10521ms
2014-07-24 15:36:13 init message: Loading wallet...
2014-07-24 15:36:13 nFileVersion = 90201
2014-07-24 15:36:13 Keys: 106 plaintext, 0 encrypted, 3 w/ metadata, 106 total
2014-07-24 15:36:13  wallet                  528ms
2014-07-24 15:36:13 init message: Rescanning...
2014-07-24 15:36:13 Rescanning last 4 blocks (from block 308573)...
2014-07-24 15:36:14  rescan                  107ms
2014-07-24 15:36:49 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001c8ceca5427284f37fc6df581b179b0ec5ddd2510c17b63f  height=308578  log2_work=79.466937  tx=41633241  date=2014-06-30 08:15:18 progress=0.921809
2014-07-24 15:36:54 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003f8b1e1424e5c38c0a83f91e393a94749a0fcf1272d20374  height=308579  log2_work=79.467061  tx=41633319  date=2014-06-30 08:16:35 progress=0.921812
2014-07-24 15:37:08 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001afc7551cda9a7f2418bfb844367a72840196a23c38c7ced  height=308580  log2_work=79.467186  tx=41633784  date=2014-06-30 08:24:54 progress=0.921831
2014-07-24 15:37:22 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000184b3f1219bb6683291a44b68c45121591d157a578f28afc  height=308581  log2_work=79.467311  tx=41634514  date=2014-06-30 08:38:54 progress=0.921862
2014-07-24 15:37:38 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000372b72fa07f71bc381fdd67175db03b82d68c8061edcff01  height=308582  log2_work=79.467435  tx=41635286  date=2014-06-30 08:55:54 progress=0.921900
2014-07-24 15:37:45 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000013ac86cb2c0ffa152d6f368b2eeef6b23b3092b44a247e5a  height=308583  log2_work=79.46756  tx=41635842  date=2014-06-30 09:08:42 progress=0.921928
2014-07-24 15:37:46 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001fc9481727b68ee051dc852b0a4f7918cdca1e574157a0c2  height=308584  log2_work=79.467685  tx=41635884  date=2014-06-30 09:04:05 progress=0.921919
2014-07-24 15:37:46 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000045c5c954d9a901e730ee9a9b00dc8c80d9053ad6cd3ce3f  height=308585  log2_work=79.467809  tx=41635885  date=2014-06-30 09:09:59 progress=0.921931
2014-07-24 15:37:48 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000007ba8dbdc7d8a5c7efd2f7446ae94ca5110ed57a3f6501d7  height=308586  log2_work=79.467934  tx=41635974  date=2014-06-30 09:04:08 progress=0.921919
2014-07-24 15:37:54 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000023174146c1a2db58befcf5de5bbdf6a68eb4874e7d049454  height=308587  log2_work=79.468059  tx=41636505  date=2014-06-30 09:23:16 progress=0.921961
2014-07-24 15:38:00 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000040676a59350d2354e3204dc3535e1b404a0c5f2b44c9e8b3  height=308588  log2_work=79.468183  tx=41636944  date=2014-06-30 09:34:20 progress=0.921985
2014-07-24 15:38:09 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000111206e0a21391596f98cd86cddedecf55ba6a928768ddab  height=308589  log2_work=79.468308  tx=41637596  date=2014-06-30 09:49:45 progress=0.922019
2014-07-24 15:38:13 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003b5cbe9f53c4323f3a9fc5998d57ac6ec546a8750c43ee9e  height=308590  log2_work=79.468433  tx=41637713  date=2014-06-30 09:47:28 progress=0.922015
2014-07-24 15:38:38 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000a6fe3b0218b6794afa7f2e071356b9756fbab11b93f21a5  height=308591  log2_work=79.468557  tx=41638600  date=2014-06-30 10:13:04 progress=0.922071
2014-07-24 15:38:41 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000097aea63e8326d91bb18d4aaf3e9eac7dd0babc66c593f0  height=308592  log2_work=79.468682  tx=41638868  date=2014-06-30 10:18:57 progress=0.922084
2014-07-24 15:38:45 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000003a48aa7c52edccab4600f6a09c37147df364a6fdeb5592d  height=308593  log2_work=79.468806  tx=41639074  date=2014-06-30 10:20:52 progress=0.922088
2014-07-24 15:38:46 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000034ef6738b06c7ec47fb3b3130703aed2e4640cc3395070d7  height=308594  log2_work=79.468931  tx=41639229  date=2014-06-30 10:21:55 progress=0.922091
2014-07-24 15:38:47 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002182d38a2e51fc4e712b182e82134f78b2cada8daeddd544  height=308595  log2_work=79.469055  tx=41639362  date=2014-06-30 10:24:21 progress=0.922097
2014-07-24 15:38:49 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002ac239e98e7c52d3a314a8f80f534a55454252bc19e2a6a0  height=308596  log2_work=79.46918  tx=41639619  date=2014-06-30 10:29:00 progress=0.922107
2014-07-24 15:38:51 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000010f64bfab31e485ec23bf01dc8577c435496f1d39186cf9f  height=308597  log2_work=79.469305  tx=41639917  date=2014-06-30 10:35:46 progress=0.922122
2014-07-24 15:39:06 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000025d2eb46162966f97cfd3b029d0870274a528df066c63d8c  height=308598  log2_work=79.469429  tx=41640607  date=2014-06-30 10:55:07 progress=0.922165
2014-07-24 15:39:12 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002f342ef0d9077dad6aa38bb81a6d30497b0f8ee5d827471b  height=308599  log2_work=79.469554  tx=41641152  date=2014-06-30 11:08:10 progress=0.922193
2014-07-24 15:39:13 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003b6a8b1204475bc916c086ffff8581d1c4f29a4983acba34  height=308600  log2_work=79.469678  tx=41641218  date=2014-06-30 11:09:24 progress=0.922196
2014-07-24 15:39:31 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002806fb7baab4332f43491929392b27d22af2ac2b5a6a8607  height=308601  log2_work=79.469803  tx=41642380  date=2014-06-30 11:38:59 progress=0.922261
2014-07-24 15:39:45 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000052b772b8c3c2e6439fb50c8654f7fce78a5a5527f59a074  height=308602  log2_work=79.469927  tx=41643702  date=2014-06-30 12:06:54 progress=0.922324
2014-07-24 15:39:48 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000003d3f3491cb225da158208e8c9902c4e4a2f43351773208a  height=308603  log2_work=79.470052  tx=41644087  date=2014-06-30 12:11:41 progress=0.922335
2014-07-24 15:39:54 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000038a448567a86b56584811f70e81e45bed5b3f74cd1a96dc6  height=308604  log2_work=79.470176  tx=41644591  date=2014-06-30 12:31:59 progress=0.922379
2014-07-24 15:40:05 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000eb826bb810b9756d3426da4796da018ce80bdd3ddd5f283  height=308605  log2_work=79.470301  tx=41645064  date=2014-06-30 12:27:29 progress=0.922371
2014-07-24 15:40:12 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000a3c9c763628d7f75a2936b0aec47b3fa76ad7fa44490545  height=308606  log2_work=79.470425  tx=41645129  date=2014-06-30 12:28:31 progress=0.922374
2014-07-24 15:40:14 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002db99b4df6f06311e2ac0ab20699727709fd5d10ad3e0c35  height=308607  log2_work=79.470549  tx=41645257  date=2014-06-30 12:41:18 progress=0.922400
2014-07-24 15:40:22 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000012b9bc5251487676f37b7528f0b3d31558a52cbe3552ec7d  height=308608  log2_work=79.470674  tx=41645574  date=2014-06-30 12:36:35 progress=0.922392
2014-07-24 15:40:40 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001a3476d6521852cafbc84866b982f6bd15983e8d7df59879  height=308609  log2_work=79.470798  tx=41646294  date=2014-06-30 12:51:12 progress=0.922424
2014-07-24 15:40:54 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002b5eccd39cca841bc8d13da1c5351aa1651ded729b2f7fce  height=308610  log2_work=79.470923  tx=41646825  date=2014-06-30 13:00:53 progress=0.922446
2014-07-24 15:40:56 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000012c8ca3b78c4bb1c3fec46771004a1c591fa571154bfc59b  height=308611  log2_work=79.471047  tx=41646853  date=2014-06-30 12:59:47 progress=0.922444
2014-07-24 15:41:01 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000032b6c1415c3441c5e0f938d68a59003deb6ed2a48511a960  height=308612  log2_work=79.471171  tx=41647498  date=2014-06-30 13:14:18 progress=0.922476
2014-07-24 15:41:14 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000395bd002f5c5390b950c1444f60eb438d75ba2c795b8dfa2  height=308613  log2_work=79.471296  tx=41648430  date=2014-06-30 13:32:12 progress=0.922516
2014-07-24 15:41:17 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000d7e3872a3633b8a383fffa9c869e08015d284f91825d6e6  height=308614  log2_work=79.47142  tx=41648552  date=2014-06-30 13:34:26 progress=0.922521
2014-07-24 15:41:19 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003f35a5677ff6625206e5573c580f79ade56f349456b6d3d1  height=308615  log2_work=79.471544  tx=41648808  date=2014-06-30 13:45:28 progress=0.922545
2014-07-24 15:41:30 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000001815a9a3c9e09d19ed45ac33e1db965e73e3f37111aa0bd  height=308616  log2_work=79.471669  tx=41649769  date=2014-06-30 14:08:08 progress=0.922595
2014-07-24 15:41:42 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000125f3b3e14b7cb60456b9ad8ffcea436f7ea7914ef32540c  height=308617  log2_work=79.471793  tx=41650261  date=2014-06-30 14:08:03 progress=0.922597
2014-07-24 15:41:57 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000040ebd7a78d8e976f5d6d59ba85edcb7ec603d4884245018e  height=308618  log2_work=79.471917  tx=41650803  date=2014-06-30 14:16:30 progress=0.922616
2014-07-24 15:42:15 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000037a619ff799488968cf0daae45ac470907db8b5165cf2be3  height=308619  log2_work=79.472042  tx=41652302  date=2014-06-30 14:55:45 progress=0.922702
2014-07-24 15:42:45 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001cfbd6e0ab530f28e4a29c958b636b2c0d497210510afc1d  height=308620  log2_work=79.472166  tx=41653116  date=2014-06-30 15:00:34 progress=0.922715
2014-07-24 15:42:59 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000c1b5e65139650add4544d633f29cb6896f13203e99de03b  height=308621  log2_work=79.47229  tx=41653805  date=2014-06-30 15:10:30 progress=0.922738
2014-07-24 15:43:10 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000033b5b3025203bb236bb4da6a0727a5ce4ca45c389e1b5fec  height=308622  log2_work=79.472415  tx=41654194  date=2014-06-30 15:13:37 progress=0.922745
2014-07-24 15:43:23 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002e7eab4e08852936f6614eac42f6b87d87cf50b9bd114f96  height=308623  log2_work=79.472539  tx=41655392  date=2014-06-30 15:37:05 progress=0.922798
2014-07-24 15:43:41 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000e997f8a250cfea0c9eb2a5e6c00c271780856a040743aaf  height=308624  log2_work=79.472663  tx=41656661  date=2014-06-30 15:57:20 progress=0.922845
2014-07-24 15:43:51 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000a4c0e38627bdd3b3a2081fa027c1f3d120e889337728ed5  height=308625  log2_work=79.472787  tx=41658129  date=2014-06-30 16:33:05 progress=0.922924
2014-07-24 15:44:04 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003ba545151c1d53bf79fe7d8c833bdd92aebd110454c6afd7  height=308626  log2_work=79.472912  tx=41658781  date=2014-06-30 16:34:40 progress=0.922929
2014-07-24 15:44:16 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003e16e877770eb01096430f971a068035869761fa6eb599a2  height=308627  log2_work=79.473036  tx=41659641  date=2014-06-30 16:43:51 progress=0.922952
2014-07-24 15:44:33 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000035d9d8caed78d928eed6acb37549cd5c38471cbb8b28553b  height=308628  log2_work=79.47316  tx=41661107  date=2014-06-30 17:13:54 progress=0.923019
2014-07-24 15:44:42 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000026dccba48b70cc21902cad05812541a25c41b4a2934948d9  height=308629  log2_work=79.473284  tx=41662254  date=2014-06-30 17:35:04 progress=0.923067
2014-07-24 15:44:45 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000e4fe3a9448b094d5565bda0dc3fc0cbdd00afe7fe090132  height=308630  log2_work=79.473408  tx=41662352  date=2014-06-30 17:27:55 progress=0.923053
2014-07-24 15:44:57 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002e4528b160d664e13ff5755a3f0db8e1ac2e79ccf545cb9b  height=308631  log2_work=79.473532  tx=41662740  date=2014-06-30 17:40:22 progress=0.923079
2014-07-24 15:44:58 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001c345915620e36ddf2ec5a33337bd535acbdc52e6df0e7ca  height=308632  log2_work=79.473657  tx=41662979  date=2014-06-30 17:42:33 progress=0.923085
2014-07-24 15:45:12 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000020429224c6caa7d7ffd06b8c37f33d1e1c5e5ce8f2f8e7fd  height=308633  log2_work=79.473781  tx=41663854  date=2014-06-30 17:55:06 progress=0.923114
2014-07-24 15:45:16 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000364713079b74cd86bef9f54aeff4e2eff2888d0a41abd3de  height=308634  log2_work=79.473905  tx=41664226  date=2014-06-30 17:59:23 progress=0.923124
2014-07-24 15:45:18 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000235b5134863a2e4f6395ac8b5cb9476cedf1a7528988dc36  height=308635  log2_work=79.474029  tx=41664395  date=2014-06-30 18:01:01 progress=0.923128
2014-07-24 15:45:31 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000019eab15cb4488d360fadf7b2bd33052c5f342c89f530df53  height=308636  log2_work=79.474153  tx=41665386  date=2014-06-30 18:18:33 progress=0.923168
2014-07-24 15:45:39 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000280ad6db622daa67744aed52a4b78ffce85139a45faab442  height=308637  log2_work=79.474277  tx=41665910  date=2014-06-30 18:25:43 progress=0.923184
2014-07-24 15:45:48 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001fa8387d649bc6133a6df30bc74a5f4829b00a4f5c40e845  height=308638  log2_work=79.474401  tx=41666807  date=2014-06-30 18:41:28 progress=0.923220
2014-07-24 15:45:56 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000f4f86482cbb360aea3eeb4bbdda441b26d57531216fcf1a  height=308639  log2_work=79.474525  tx=41667224  date=2014-06-30 18:47:24 progress=0.923234
2014-07-24 15:45:58 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000018f4705984f1fa1c4da9af457722d88e16a6de38fe4eaff1  height=308640  log2_work=79.47465  tx=41667320  date=2014-06-30 18:48:00 progress=0.923236
2014-07-24 15:46:17 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000f8dd862afbf16e7b2069e00a768ab93d66963c7c7b802b9  height=308641  log2_work=79.474774  tx=41668430  date=2014-06-30 19:07:37 progress=0.923280
2014-07-24 15:46:25 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000af3d93c872da61c1be9d6cd78781219330cc8df3d3222b6  height=308642  log2_work=79.474898  tx=41668879  date=2014-06-30 19:15:00 progress=0.923297
2014-07-24 15:46:28 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002eb65c7df237d2ce5ebbdfcbd1dd33447c15f42c4212b5c7  height=308643  log2_work=79.475022  tx=41669111  date=2014-06-30 19:17:12 progress=0.923302
2014-07-24 15:46:30 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001aa5eff90ca2c055ff28a0e95fe3b3f2db398d142e04ff08  height=308644  log2_work=79.475146  tx=41669238  date=2014-06-30 19:19:23 progress=0.923307
2014-07-24 15:46:40 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000a641b00fd31182f061ae5b2beeb4d171d508fe0406a4f48  height=308645  log2_work=79.47527  tx=41669962  date=2014-06-30 19:31:36 progress=0.923335
2014-07-24 15:46:48 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001122e170c210b6bd8b4955a9a0433ffddabab27f5e393f12  height=308646  log2_work=79.475394  tx=41670254  date=2014-06-30 19:35:13 progress=0.923343
2014-07-24 15:46:49 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001a23b1575f6a8ae505173a348c400e7ea2bc21779e3e4c4a  height=308647  log2_work=79.475518  tx=41670512  date=2014-06-30 19:38:28 progress=0.923351
2014-07-24 15:46:54 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002375abedd1475782ad7533f291bfd82ea782b13802ed7185  height=308648  log2_work=79.475642  tx=41670855  date=2014-06-30 19:43:59 progress=0.923364
2014-07-24 15:46:57 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000a4b4abc2492685015aeb5661f33958a910b5174a92d7a5a  height=308649  log2_work=79.475766  tx=41671475  date=2014-06-30 19:53:27 progress=0.923386
2014-07-24 15:47:02 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000019ce04eac4567334e88b176957903fed168328a05e7a52eb  height=308650  log2_work=79.47589  tx=41671833  date=2014-06-30 19:57:44 progress=0.923396
2014-07-24 15:47:03 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000395379540da9e6e5d3419ec6bca69427ca325901f9c788b6  height=308651  log2_work=79.476014  tx=41671911  date=2014-06-30 19:58:31 progress=0.923398
2014-07-24 15:47:18 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000089113b064e6997a615e1445a5dc7d0bec6716be0d616795  height=308652  log2_work=79.476138  tx=41673316  date=2014-06-30 20:19:17 progress=0.923446
2014-07-24 15:47:20 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000056efa8ca8b3851ac7c44f3e72ec54b4d1352a1a39097937  height=308653  log2_work=79.476262  tx=41673733  date=2014-06-30 20:25:14 progress=0.923460
2014-07-24 15:47:21 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000c135b0dfd6ff8ec599a04557f10c5a03255033310d83fd1  height=308654  log2_work=79.476386  tx=41673879  date=2014-06-30 20:26:34 progress=0.923463
2014-07-24 15:47:39 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000303a9f670160a2bcc73f20cf8ad8bedcc0b393b45d808050  height=308655  log2_work=79.476509  tx=41675242  date=2014-06-30 20:46:54 progress=0.923510
(... running out of space so skipping a whole bunch of them...)
2014-07-24 16:08:53 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000036dcb0b748d09f88fc6892990531c5b591af61ca7e2aaf2  height=308856  log2_work=79.501203  tx=41776633  date=2014-07-02 09:18:33 progress=0.928397
2014-07-24 16:08:54 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000bd775aeb9c293a4b0173b71578b4059adfdf82f72788f5a  height=308857  log2_work=79.501325  tx=41776715  date=2014-07-02 09:20:50 progress=0.928402
2014-07-24 16:09:00 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000011cf9d68d8dd026bc2e452b80c7abe9f531cff52d967b7f9  height=308858  log2_work=79.501447  tx=41777314  date=2014-07-02 09:39:23 progress=0.928443
2014-07-24 16:09:05 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003bfa1c0797bc58cc7cce33a62a41c61d993c94e2ca9540f8  height=308859  log2_work=79.501569  tx=41777875  date=2014-07-02 09:54:55 progress=0.928477
2014-07-24 16:09:05 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000238b799d2c6d0a2e4f6209eef371a421d2a59f99eafdc4b8  height=308860  log2_work=79.50169  tx=41777950  date=2014-07-02 09:55:51 progress=0.928479
2014-07-24 16:09:06 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000206aa39175891590e9bb071335c5f9c21522341c9ea0a369  height=308861  log2_work=79.501812  tx=41778014  date=2014-07-02 10:02:36 progress=0.928494
2014-07-24 16:09:09 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002d8c8413bd0988673871bcaf8b8f9d89d31cc8334543d559  height=308862  log2_work=79.501934  tx=41778368  date=2014-07-02 10:07:31 progress=0.928505
2014-07-24 16:09:11 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000d8f59e9b42ff4f8204e34af890ba5ed612b62f5e364974f  height=308863  log2_work=79.502056  tx=41778474  date=2014-07-02 10:09:53 progress=0.928510
2014-07-24 16:09:14 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000061c412002b4ee3f10f3e41f53b02e57d521192aa1b648e2  height=308864  log2_work=79.502177  tx=41778785  date=2014-07-02 10:17:35 progress=0.928527
2014-07-24 16:09:14 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000017ca051b1e8dbe25361dbf12855d478a7cad32932c3bf267  height=308865  log2_work=79.502299  tx=41778813  date=2014-07-02 10:18:25 progress=0.928529
2014-07-24 16:09:15 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003af5d259cb593e7a39c0d098786fbe52898eadafb938b11f  height=308866  log2_work=79.502421  tx=41778955  date=2014-07-02 10:21:20 progress=0.928536
2014-07-24 16:09:21 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003a5ecd43069ca99f13ab8509038379961149766cf9f5ea98  height=308867  log2_work=79.502543  tx=41779550  date=2014-07-02 10:38:48 progress=0.928574
2014-07-24 16:09:21 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000410cd4a123f6c1c779906c02fd1cd7aeeaab06924ca3f6b2  height=308868  log2_work=79.502664  tx=41779757  date=2014-07-02 10:43:38 progress=0.928585
2014-07-24 16:09:25 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003f9dacb1f6ef9dc478d826544aaca3706e60ca0e7150c30b  height=308869  log2_work=79.502786  tx=41780284  date=2014-07-02 10:54:01 progress=0.928608
2014-07-24 16:09:28 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000040a9e0ac550b205de0a163f6dd7e37444502f6357e3e122f  height=308870  log2_work=79.502908  tx=41780762  date=2014-07-02 11:04:58 progress=0.928633
2014-07-24 16:09:31 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000034c24eaeb5ff0442a2edf25a3fff1ba1509b61315c494a37  height=308871  log2_work=79.503029  tx=41781149  date=2014-07-02 11:14:26 progress=0.928654
2014-07-24 16:09:32 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000019bb1d7392818853d827b7b0e294d5dc6e7b42c24ccaad9b  height=308872  log2_work=79.503151  tx=41781227  date=2014-07-02 11:14:47 progress=0.928655
2014-07-24 16:09:34 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000faf6885b0e592d24a83d05485dc05355b31fa54cf8bfb9f  height=308873  log2_work=79.503273  tx=41781518  date=2014-07-02 11:22:21 progress=0.928671
2014-07-24 16:09:40 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003aac9928ccfa4df7ca468ac2aa08759ebbf58a4a37d96577  height=308874  log2_work=79.503394  tx=41781903  date=2014-07-02 11:31:56 progress=0.928692
2014-07-24 16:09:49 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000146a506438366be7103c0e01166f80410d2049db8c610d64  height=308875  log2_work=79.503516  tx=41782931  date=2014-07-02 11:58:46 progress=0.928752
2014-07-24 16:09:51 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000ffccf436d7bf017766cb79cfaed9e3c5571b3e2e4b7517e  height=308876  log2_work=79.503637  tx=41783187  date=2014-07-02 12:10:12 progress=0.928776
2014-07-24 16:10:00 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003df9c7b61b762332080ca2bb93a07cd3d8d0ffcc74ad62d0  height=308877  log2_work=79.503759  tx=41783690  date=2014-07-02 12:14:42 progress=0.928787
2014-07-24 16:10:09 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000088ea666d9a17333daf3e41f54b5877d11f43bacbf4f0c5a  height=308878  log2_work=79.503881  tx=41784029  date=2014-07-02 12:21:43 progress=0.928803
2014-07-24 16:10:16 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000403754920681189fbd329dbd806b94651ab4d57cfd07b662  height=308879  log2_work=79.504002  tx=41784370  date=2014-07-02 12:28:01 progress=0.928817
2014-07-24 16:10:36 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000235f9b198c2dfd32218e48e56bb2b2761ae8d87ab26f8ad9  height=308880  log2_work=79.504124  tx=41784705  date=2014-07-02 12:32:31 progress=0.928827
2014-07-24 16:10:58 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000034fd959ce61bf13ba244836b16e1a0ed1e0c8f0b1a8126b2  height=308881  log2_work=79.504245  tx=41786480  date=2014-07-02 13:16:44 progress=0.928924
2014-07-24 16:11:12 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002793f686ec8fd0fc82b4e60421b492586dd560ad84cdb9e7  height=308882  log2_work=79.504367  tx=41787256  date=2014-07-02 13:33:41 progress=0.928962
2014-07-24 16:11:14 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000205bb223e37996de2c1c78fbf596787721a30c2d19c86c56  height=308883  log2_work=79.504488  tx=41787512  date=2014-07-02 13:46:08 progress=0.928989
2014-07-24 16:11:19 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000d3e581ab7987e5cef1f3c8387ca09b17b3ed755a49e1895  height=308884  log2_work=79.50461  tx=41788175  date=2014-07-02 13:48:48 progress=0.928996
2014-07-24 16:11:26 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000007ccbef5b4d838a24742db01e86014d7bb4fd1b16d160dee  height=308885  log2_work=79.504731  tx=41788431  date=2014-07-02 13:51:29 progress=0.929003
2014-07-24 16:11:40 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003d9f50c129560d42dff5731ec61665362575916e131d4490  height=308886  log2_work=79.504853  tx=41789093  date=2014-07-02 14:01:52 progress=0.929026
2014-07-24 16:11:47 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000020872506f40951c3d5766d399a50effcd9419d5b1041ba5f  height=308887  log2_work=79.504974  tx=41789510  date=2014-07-02 14:08:28 progress=0.929041
2014-07-24 16:11:51 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002110c9c99b2f141c5bc1c51c0a3536b4be68e84f24c2659a  height=308888  log2_work=79.505096  tx=41789730  date=2014-07-02 14:11:43 progress=0.929049
2014-07-24 16:11:55 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000f32ab6cbc1bde47b68c35e0c588f5681c48f2608a81ab60  height=308889  log2_work=79.505217  tx=41789938  date=2014-07-02 14:13:48 progress=0.929054
2014-07-24 16:11:59 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001ae3aabca8a7bdfd8f5066603a05f78d02082886ef3a04b8  height=308890  log2_work=79.505339  tx=41790158  date=2014-07-02 14:17:05 progress=0.929061
2014-07-24 16:12:27 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000cc15cadbe8642a9da196beace3413a45180e31e30442330  height=308891  log2_work=79.50546  tx=41790446  date=2014-07-02 14:21:10 progress=0.929070
2014-07-24 16:12:59 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003bd0bc063d53d60473e9adb7d891ee259d275cfdb1796845  height=308892  log2_work=79.505582  tx=41790712  date=2014-07-02 14:24:44 progress=0.929077
2014-07-24 16:13:06 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000016e93ac9e00f93d2a6d530bf6e8030ade14270909ebe7ef5  height=308893  log2_work=79.505703  tx=41791211  date=2014-07-02 14:33:36 progress=0.929097
2014-07-24 16:13:27 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000018dd41fc55222a5c94a6fe45940ee91cd3be6d673571e378  height=308894  log2_work=79.505825  tx=41791608  date=2014-07-02 14:43:06 progress=0.929118
2014-07-24 16:13:36 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002a1d068606e67d09a964a800edacbf5b765e3bc4d2ee5f3a  height=308895  log2_work=79.505946  tx=41791935  date=2014-07-02 14:47:21 progress=0.929127
2014-07-24 16:13:52 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000003771d2a06984d5ab72b7284b5be72380c07d71d96e79eae1  height=308896  log2_work=79.506067  tx=41792691  date=2014-07-02 15:02:07 progress=0.929160
2014-07-24 16:13:59 UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000034b5fe5281b064310427ca0e6955512e097c817bdafdb3c6  height=308897  log2_work=79.506189  tx=41792895  date=2014-07-02 15:04:50 progress=0.929166
2014-07-24 16:14:01 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000001bf64995fe5f44fa15845bd638dc0a26b2cd6c6d6d13be11  height=308898  log2_work=79.50631  tx=41793074  date=2014-07-02 15:07:11 progress=0.929172
2014-07-24 16:14:10 UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000002479b6320d7e0bf85f135d1efa1d3ee2042074f2cd53b7c4  height=308899  log2_work=79.506432  tx=41794125  date=2014-07-02 15:32:10 progress=0.929227
2014-07-24 16:14:24 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000187b91020b29b9ffd6837ad5506fd92cabdc2bad57e93022  height=308900  log2_work=79.506553  tx=41794999  date=2014-07-02 15:43:30 progress=0.929254
2014-07-24 16:14:49 UpdateTip: new best=0000000000000000046cca966885e7d98da570d7b98177926da2a24de672de4a  height=308901  log2_work=79.506674  tx=41795693  date=2014-07-02 15:53:31 progress=0.929276
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Bitcoin detects that there are blocks in its block database that have not yet been processed, it processes them all at startup, as a recovery mechanism. It may mean that somehow blocks were downloaded, but the node crashed before they were processed. So basically, you're doing all validation for the new blocks since the previous run in one go.

I presume you're syncing the blocks/* data, but not the chainstate/*? If you would synchronize the latter too, Bitcoin would have the processed result too.

If the CPU usage is too high for you, set `-par=1` on the command line (or `par=1` in bitcoin.conf), which will limit validation to a single thread/core (meaning it will take longer as well).

Evidence: the 'last block file' log line mentions heights up to 312279, but the initial best tip (=up to where the chainstate is computed) has height 308577.

Comment: You are very right... I am not syncing the chainstate/* directories! This must be it. Let me try to figure out how to do that, but I'll ask a question about that in another thread as not to confuse the topic.

Answer (score 0):

In an earlier Version of bitcoin-qt the line was the following:

> SetBestChain: new best=0000000000000419f719  height=212580  work=666804971104474944731

From: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=136628.0

> In the log messages, new best is the start of the hash of the block
>   that it considers to be the head of the best chain, height is the
>   length of the path through the tree, and work is the sum of the work
>   embedded in that path.

It basically means that your client received a new best blockchain, so a new block was found. You can compare those log entries, they will allways increase in height.

I'm not sure why this is CPU intense for you, i didn't recognized this at my client yet. There is no way to remove this function because its a fundamental one of bitcoin-qt client and the bitcoin protocol. Also making it less CPU intense can only be done by changing the source of the client and this would most likely make it take even longer.

Comment: It's not receiving a new best block; it already has it at startup. Otherwise, yes, this is what it is doing.